# It is possible to use GoogleMaps without compiling with Google APIs?

Tags: android, google-api, android-mapview, android-library

Some devices, like vexia zippers tab 9i tablet (300€ tablet, not chinese tablet) haves an Android version that does not includes Maps. The device haves his stock OS version and it is not a chinese tablet.

If i try to use an app that it is compiled with Google APIs, i get this error:

```
08-11 08:51:37.644: E/PackageManager(403): Package com.myapp.test requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!

Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

It is impossible to install and use apps that needs google maps in this kind of tablets? Can i compile a app that needs Google Maps with SDK instead of GOogle Apis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to run such apps without google api.

Comment: but, i can install google maps app in the tablet, why google maps app is avaiable in market and installable if the tablet can not execute apps that uses maps?